# Deploy Play Scala app on Heroku

Tags: java, scala, heroku

I have a sample app written in Play and Scala talking to Amazon DynamoDB and I'm trying to deploy it onto Heroku. Heroku only has instructions to deploy either a Play app or Scala app but not both. I have attempted to merge the instructions for both but coming up short. I'm seeing this error,

```
  [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /tmp/build_1q6humfwtqitn/.sbt_home/.sbt/plugins/target/scala-2.9.1/sbt-0.11.2/classes...
   [info] Loading project definition from /tmp/build_1q6humfwtqitn/project
   [warn]   module not found: com.typesafe.startscript#xsbt-start-script-plugin;0.3.0
   [warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
   [warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.startscript/xsbt-start-script-plugin/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.2/0.3.0/ivys/ivy.xml
   [warn] ==== local: tried
   [warn]   /tmp/build_1q6humfwtqitn/.sbt_home/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.startscript/xsbt-start-script-plugin/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.2/0.3.0/ivys/ivy.xml
   [warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
   [warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.startscript/xsbt-start-script-plugin/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.2/0.3.0/ivys/ivy.xml
   [warn] ==== heroku-sbt-typesafe: tried
   [warn] ==== heroku-central: tried
   [warn]   http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/com/typesafe/startscript/xsbt-start-script-plugin_2.9.1_0.11.2/0.3.0/xsbt-start-script-plugin-0.3.0.pom
   [warn] ==== heroku-scala-tools-releases: tried
   [warn]   http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-scala-tools-releases/com/typesafe/startscript/xsbt-start-script-plugin_2.9.1_0.11.2/0.3.0/xsbt-start-script-plugin-0.3.0.pom
   [warn] ==== heroku-scala-tools-snapshots: tried
   [warn]   http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-scala-tools-snapshots/com/typesafe/startscript/xsbt-start-script-plugin_2.9.1_0.11.2/0.3.0/xsbt-start-script-plugin-0.3.0.pom
   [warn] ==== heroku-sbt-typesafe: tried
   [warn] ==== heroku-central: tried
   [warn]   http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/com/typesafe/startscript/xsbt-start-script-plugin_2.9.1_0.11.2/0.3.0/xsbt-start-script-plugin-0.3.0.pom
   [warn] ==== heroku-scala-tools-releases: tried
   [warn]   http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-scala-tools-releases/com/typesafe/startscript/xsbt-start-script-plugin_2.9.1_0.11.2/0.3.0/xsbt-start-script-plugin-0.3.0.pom
   [warn] ==== heroku-scala-tools-snapshots: tried
   [warn]   http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-scala-tools-snapshots/com/typesafe/startscript/xsbt-start-script-plugin_2.9.1_0.11.2/0.3.0/xsbt-start-script-plugin-0.3.0.pom
   [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
   [warn]   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
   [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
   [warn]   :: com.typesafe.startscript#xsbt-start-script-plugin;0.3.0: not found
   [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
   [warn] 
   [warn]   Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
   [warn]       com.typesafe.startscript:xsbt-start-script-plugin:0.3.0 (sbtVersion=0.11.2, scalaVersion=2.9.1)
   [warn] 
   [error] {file:/tmp/build_1q6humfwtqitn/project/}default-646eae/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.startscript#xsbt-start-script-plugin;0.3.0: not found
   Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?  !     Failed to build app with SBT 0.11.0
   ! Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Scala app
```

Also, I'm new to Java, Play and Scala but am familiar with deploying Rails app on Heroku.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but I noticed this recently. Hope it helps. http://www.jamesward.com/2012/02/21/play-framework-2-with-scala-anorm-json-coffeescript-jquery-heroku

Comment: If this is Play 2 then check out the instructions for deploying on Heroku: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ProductionHeroku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either change your version of `com.typesafe.startscript:xsbt-start-script-plugin:0.3.0` to 0.5.0 (where ever you have specified this dependency) or edit build.properties file to set `sbt.version=0.11.0`.

Comment: The `xsbt-start-script-plugin` shouldn't be needed for a Play app.